# Unable to apply SSL Binding in Azure to Web App Service

Tags: azure, ssl, certificate

I've imported a Private Certificate through Azure which it's given a status of healthy so assume all the verification is correct.  However when I try to add an SSL Binding I'm not given any options in the Hostname.

I'm following the tutorial below and my experience in the 'Bind certificate to app' section

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-purchase-ssl-web-site

Certificate looks to have been imported:
[image]

No binding options:
[image]

I've added a custom domain which has validated but I still don't have the option.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a domain or hostname first to be able to add binding.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZI5X.png)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZI5X.png]

Comment: Hello Hannel, thank you very much for responding.  Unfortunately I've added the custom domain which has validated itself but it's still not pulling through on the SSL binding.

Comment: Make sure its showing [here](https://i.imgur.com/qYMToTe.png), some times there is a delay.  Once it there then you should have it in the options [like this](https://i.imgur.com/ROBPuyE.png).  Done this dozens of times, if for some reason is not working for you them you might need an support ticket.

Comment: and after a few minutes and a refresh it's up and running.  Easy when you know how.  Thank you, answer accepted.